# How to query the data present in Stream[java.io.File] in Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Using Scala I am trying to list all the files in a directory and then read the file attributes. 
In my case, I am trying to read the file attribute: creation date.
The files are present in local and after doing some research, I was able to list all the files in a directory in Linux using the below code:

```
import java.io.File
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

def getFileTree(f: File): Stream[File] =
        f #:: (if (f.isDirectory) f.listFiles().toStream.flatMap(getFileTree) 
               else Stream.empty)

val filesList = getFileTree(new File("/tmp/hive_audits/"))
```

fileList is created in the following format:

```
files: Stream[java.io.File] = Stream(/tmp/hive_audits, ?)
```

I understood that it is in the form of a collection. But I unable to understand how to query the 'fileList', like iterate thru the files present in the directory and then get the creation date of it.
Could anyone let me know how can I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through with `.foreach` also with `for (file <- files) {...}`:

```
 for (file <- files) println(new java.util.Date(file.lastModified))
```

The [`java.io.File`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/File.html) API does not support creation date.